# Postgresql 12 doesn´t find PostGIS extension on CentOS 8

Tags: postgresql, postgis, centos8

I´m trying to get PostGIS working, but it seems that Postgresql doesn´t find the extension. My server is running on CentOS 8, the Postgresql is version 12. I installed Postgresql 12 first via `dnf module enable postgresql:12` etc..

Afterwards I installed PostGIS and followed the description on the PostGIS website (https://people.planetpostgresql.org/devrim/index.php?/archives/102-Installing-PostGIS-3.0-and-PostgreSQL-12-on-CentOS-8.html). But when I try to run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` I get the error `ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-3": No such file or directory SQL state: 58P01` I figured out that the needed files reside in a subdirectory "bitcode". Therefore I tried to symlink the content in the $libdir directory above - but didn´t help. Even copying them in the directory didn´t - same error. What am I missing?

Thank you and best regards,
Goetz

Comment: Remove all symbolic links and other things you created manually. What you found is an unrelated file. Perhaps you mixed installations with the PGDG binaries and the ones provided by your distribution. What do you get for `rpm -qa|grep postgres`? The file should be in `/usr/pgsql-12/lib`.

Comment: I get: postgresql-12.1-2.module_el8.1.0+273+979c16e6.x86_64
postgresql12-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
postgresql12-contrib-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
postgresql12-libs-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
postgresql12-server-12.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64
postgresql-server-12.1-2.module_el8.1.0+273+979c16e6.x86_64

Comment: Maybe the best thing would be to get rid of Postgres and PostGIS - and install it from scratch. What should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mix of packages installed: Some from the CentOS distribution, some from the PostgreSQL site. That will lead to trouble.

Uninstall the PostgreSQL packages that do *not* have PGDG in them and make sure to disable them as shown in the link you show. Then install the PGDG packages for PostGIS

Comment: It worked - thank you very much. Beste Grüße Götz