# How to install postgis on this Centos 8 system? Getting "Error: Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job"

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, postgis

Related question: [Why is installing PostGIS 3 on RHEL 8 / CentOS 8 impossible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405357/why-is-installing-postgis-3-on-rhel-8-centos-8-impossible)

System versions:
CentOS, 8
Postgres, 12.3

This is a production db so I cannot uninstall/reinstall postgres. I did `dnf install postgis31_13` on a different server with no issues and can't figure out why it's not working on this system.

I try to do `dnf install postgis31_12` and it returns the following error:

```
[user@computer ~]# dnf install postgis31_12
Last metadata expiration check: 0:21:12 ago on Tue Oct 19 19:22:40 2021.
Error:
 Problem: cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides geos39 >= 3.9.1 needed by postgis31_12-3.1.4-1.rhel8.x86_64
  - nothing provides gdal33-libs >= 3.3.1 needed by postgis31_12-3.1.4-1.rhel8.x86_64
  - nothing provides proj81 >= 8.1.0 needed by postgis31_12-3.1.4-1.rhel8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libSFCGAL.so.1()(64bit) needed by postgis31_12-3.1.4-1.rhel8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libproj.so.22()(64bit) needed by postgis31_12-3.1.4-1.rhel8.x86_64
  - nothing provides SFCGAL needed by postgis31_12-3.1.4-1.rhel8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libgeotiff16 needed by postgis31_12-3.1.4-1.rhel8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libgdal.so.29()(64bit) needed by postgis31_12-3.1.4-1.rhel8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I tried `dnf install postgis31_12 --nobest` and that returns the same thing but about triple the number of lines of "nothing provides ..."

Other things I tried which didn't do anything:

- different `postgis` versions
- retrying after `dnf install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm`
- `dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install postgis31_12` from the related question
- `dnf --disablerepo AppStream install postgis31_12`
- this series of commands from the related question:

```
dnf -y install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
dnf -qy module disable postgresql
yum -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
dnf --enablerepo=PowerTools install postgresql12-contrib postgis30_12
```

On the other working server (also Centos 8) I did `dnf list --installed` and noticed `geos39` and `SFCGAL` are present and from the `@pgdg-common` repository, which is detailed [here on postgresql.org](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/announcing-common-yum-repository-2027/) and I believe downloaded from here: https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

I think I need to somehow make the `dnf install` include the `@pgdg-common` repository but I'm not sure how (or if it already is). I have already downloaded it... is there something else I need to do with it? Is there some other issues, or any other information that can clarify the situation?

---

edit: `dnf list | grep pgdg-common` returns nothing. Definitely looks like `dnf install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm` did not make `pgdg-common` available to `dnf` but I believe that's all that should be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being that

```
dnf install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-8-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

created a `pgdg-redhat-all.repo.rpmnew` in `/etc/yum.repos.d/`. This happens when `pgdg-redhat-all.repo` has been edited and was resolved by adding the `pgdg-common` stuff from `pgdg-redhat-all.repo.rpmnew` to `pgdg-redhat-all.repo`. Then I ran `dnf install postgis31_12` and it completed successfully.

This scenario is accounted for in https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/announcing-common-yum-repository-2027/